# Get sorted list of the top voted Models from DB

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

*Using: Rails 4.1.4, PostgreSQL 9.1.13*

Hi. I'm have a simple problem, but for some reason I can't get it done. The picture is this:

**Models**

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many   :votes
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :articles
  has_many :votes
end

class Vote < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :article
  belongs_to :user, scope: :hotel_id

  validates_inclusion_of  :value, in: 0..5
  validates_uniqueness_of :user_id, :article_id
end
```

**Idea**

- Each User can Vote for each Article but only once (to avoid multiple voting).
- Vote model has a 'value' attribute that is the range 0..10.
- ArticlesController except standard CRUD methods has action #showcase which must return 5 articles with the top votes rating from the DB and sort them in the descending order (and render the respective view).

So I understand that the proper way is to write the class method in the Article Model (smth. like "by_top_votes") and use it in the ArticlesController#showcase:

```
def showcase
  @top_five_articles = Article.by_top_votes
end
```

The problem is that I can't write the proper query to the DB which will: 1)find articles, 2)find all votes of the each article, 3) sum all values of the respective article's votes, 4)sort them (this step I know how to do).

Thank you for reading and for the help.

**P.S.** Maybe my way to solve problem is almost wrong. If this so, please tell my the right one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've done it by myself. If anybody will stuck with the same problem, here is solution for it.

**1.** In Vote model summarize the vote's values:

```
def self.sum_value
  sum(:value)
end
```

**2.** Add new attribute (and column) to Article - `user_rating:integer`.

**3.** In the Article model define two class methods:

```
# assign user_rating attribute with the sum of all votes values
def set_user_rating
  user_rating = self.votes.sum_value
  self.update_attribute(:user_rating, user_rating)
end

# get top 5 articles by user_rating value from db
def self.top_by_user_rating
  Article.order(:user_rating).reverse_order.limit(5)
end
```

**4.** In the `ArticlesController` define `showcase` action:

```
def showcase
  @top_articles = Article.top_by_user_rating               
end
```

**5**. In the `VotesController` define `create` action:

```
  def create
    @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
    @vote = @article.votes.create(vote_params)
    if @vote.save
      @article.set_user_rating
      redirect_to @article, notice: "Thanks for your vote"
    else
      .
    end
  end
```

It works and tests are passing.